# Font size for a php snippet WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, divi

I have a price suffix for products on a WooCommerce Store build using DIVI.
The price and the suffix are the same font size and bold.

How do i reduce the font size for the suffix only?
I got this which add the part i need but can't figure out the bit to reduce font size and/or make it not bold?

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'bbloomer_add_price_suffix', 99, 4 );
  
function bbloomer_add_price_suffix( $html, $product, $price, $qty ){
    $html .= ' (p/box) +VAT';
    return $html;
}
```

Maybe there is an easier way using the {price_excluding_tax} filter ... ?

Thanks

site is https://tpls.co.uk/product/armstrong-hydroboard-board-1200-x-600mm-square-edge-ceiling-tiles/

Answer (score 0):

You can add this CSS to your theme's style.css file.
Or in DIVI theme `DIVI -> Theme options -> general -> Custom CSS`.

```
.price small.woocommerce-price-suffix {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```